# Question about pickup phase

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups, electronics, wiring

I currently have a hss guitar setup with a coil split and a five way blade selector. in 2st position with the coil split, it’s like a regular hss Strat with the middle single coil and the slug coil of the humbucker, but if I put the coil split switch off, the whole series humbucker is combined with the middle single coil. Is the screw coil and the middle single coil in this situation technically out of phase?

Comment: Do you have a wiring scheme for it? Technically it maybe out-of-phase or in-phase. Depends all on the internal wiring. On the other hand you can measure with an oscilloscope or pc soundcard (direct in) the phase by using some metal (iron) and watching the direction of the deflection when you move it towards one of the 2 pickups. Out of phase the deflection will be in opposite direction (i.e. up-down down-up)